# Add an extra text that appears on selected variations in WooCommerce

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, hook-woocommerce, product-variations

I would like to add a function that fires when the customer selects a product variant. Just as the price appears (after choosing variants).

It is a simple function (from functions.php) that reads additional information about productions from the database.
However, I do not know if there is such a hook?

Comment: Duplicate of this question: https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/276941/woocommerce-add-extra-field-to-variation-product , follow the answer.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it is a duplicate of https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/276941/woocommerce-add-extra-field-to-variation-product

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To add a text on selecting a variation you can use the following:

```
add_filter('woocommerce_available_variation', 'variation_custom_text', 10, 3 );
function variation_custom_text( $variation_data, $product, $variation ) {
    // Here your custom text
    $custom_text = __("This is my custom text…", "woocommerce");

    $variation_data['availability_html'] .= '<p>' . $custom_text . '</p>';

    return $variation_data;
}
```

Code goes in function.php file of the active child theme (or active theme). Tested and works.

[image]